# Best performance for updating many Highcharts instances on demand

Tags: javascript, loops, highcharts, coffeescript

I currently have a page with some Highcharts graphics, around 22, and they are subject to filters selectable by the user. Each filter interaction removes the current series and adds new ones.

I started with two approaches, the first consisted in having a loop that went through all saved instance objects, removing each serie,

```
while currentChart.series.length > 0
  currentChart.series[currentChart.series.length - 1].remove()
```

and then, after another loop that goes through arrays to search for the filter data and

```
currentChart.addSeries
  name: operatorName
  data: data
  type: options.chartType
```

but this implementation turned out to be quite heavy.

I then implemented a timeout to let the plugin breathe a little and don't stack as much, by setting a 1ms timeout between each loop I got better performance and could see the animations but It makes it a bit sluggish. Setting a higher timeout makes the page hard to navigate and filter changes would stack, as the entire graphics update would take much time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, when I have a large number of charts or datapoints, I generally turn off animation. Animation adds a lot over processing overhead, and without it highcharts generally handles a lot of data very well.

I guess you could try removing the series and adding the new one for each chart at a time, rather than removing all and then adding all. I doublt this will make much different to your page responsiveness though.

```
  chart: {
      animation: false
  },
  plotOptions: {
        series: {
            animation: false
        }
  },
```

Comment: In this case the obvious solution is the more efective. I guess I'll have to work with no animation to provide the best UX.

Comment: wow I didn't think the animation part would cause my charts to not display, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
while currentChart.series.length > 0
  currentChart.series[0].destroy()
```

ex: http://jsfiddle.net/5B9c7/1/

Comment: Providing some context would benefit this answer.